# HTML code for Newsletter

Tags: html, newsletter

I am doing a project and I need to create a newsletter for it.
I search in Google for code examples how to create a newsletter using HTML but I couldn't find anything. Can anyone help me with posting some code how to create a newsletter using html ?
I am using CodeIgniter for my project.

Any idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: Would you please explain more about newsletter? Do you want everything done on client-side or you want using PHP?

Comment: I want the HTML form...so the one that the user has to complete so it can be registered on newsletters and then he/she can have news via email. Am I clear ?

Comment: What about server-side coding? PHP/.Net/NodeJs/...? Do you want database for storing newsletter content as well? Using MySQL or file-based?

Comment: No,I am using MySQL ;) But I only want the code for creating the newsletter...only the form :D

Comment: You mean you want a system for users to subscribe to your newsletters and not creating the actual newsletters?

Answer (score 1):

Here are several tips I use everyday for building great HTML newsletters.

Many of the restrictions described below exist because of Microsoft Outlook (which uses Word to interpret HTML code).

1/ use HTML 4 transitionnal (avoid XHTML and strict DTD)

2/ specify full HTML 4 DTD like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

3/ host your images on a fast webserver

4/ use inline css (within your HTML tags) like this :

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">Your text</p>
```

5/ avoid image-only newsletter (or your work could most likely be considered as spam)

6/ use tables for building your email layout (forget all about divs, absolute positioning, iframe, etc...)

7/ always provide a link to view your HMTL in a browser

8/ always provide a link to unsubscribe

9/ forget about using animated gifs (outlook 2007 and 2010 block the animation on the first frame)

10/ use basic old-school HTML for a better compatibility

11/ don't use forms

12/ don't use background images (many email clients simply don't display them)

13/ no Flash, no plugins, no external css

14/ test, test, test before sending

By the way, Outlook 2007 behaves like 2010.

Comment: 4, 7, 8 and 14 are useful tips, but I doubt 1 & 2 make that much of a difference and I downright disagree with 6.